# When trying to define array with variables swift gives error

Tags: arrays, variables, swift

```
 var test = "Activity One name"
 var actNames = [test]
```

Swift gives error saying `ViewController.type` does not have member named `test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can't initialize a property (like `actNames`) by referring to another property (like `test`). The reason is that at this time the instance itself does not yet exist - that is what we are in the middle of initializing!

The workaround is to declare to `actnames` as `lazy`. Now it is not initialized until after the rest of the instance, including `test`, has come into existence:

```
var test = "Activity One name"
lazy var actNames : [String] = [self.test]
```

Note that the explicit `self` here is required (might be a bug in Swift or not, hard to tell).